# iAd Crash Report

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, iad

I am seeing the following crash log in Crashlytics with an iOS app. It is certainly infrequent, and I have been unable to replicate, but it is very annoying.

Anyone able to suggest what this is likely linked to?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019548c0b4 objc_retain + 20
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x0000000195b0dbf8 _Block_object_assign + 320
2  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x0000000195b0d738 _Block_copy_internal + 384
3  UIKit                          0x0000000189b49988 +[_UIAsyncInvocation invocationWithBlock:] + 84
4  UIKit                          0x0000000189b2e378 +[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest __requestRemoteViewController:service:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:serializedAppearanceCustomizations:legacyAppearance:exportedHostingObject:serviceViewControllerDeputyInterface:connectionHandler:] + 1320
5  UIKit                          0x0000000189b2e7a8 +[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest requestViewController:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:serializedAppearanceCustomizations:legacyAppearance:exportedHostingObject:serviceViewControllerDeputyInterface:connectionHandler:] + 72
6  UIKit                          0x0000000189b30b00 +[_UIRemoteViewController _requestViewController:traitCollection:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:service:connectionHandler:] + 528
7  iAd                            0x000000018a12c130 +[ADAdSpaceRemoteViewController adSpaceRemoteViewControllerWithCompletionHandler:] + 96
8  iAd                            0x000000018a126908 -[ADAdSpace _requestServiceAdSpace] + 228
9  iAd                            0x000000018a1264ac __30-[ADAdSpace initForRecipient:]_block_invoke + 36
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000195ab93ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000195ab936c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000195abd980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
13 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184cd5fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184cd404c __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184c010a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
16 GraphicsServices               0x000000018dda35a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
17 UIKit                          0x00000001895363c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
18 xxxxxxxx                       0x00000001000d6380 main (main.m:16)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000195ae2a08 start + 4
```

Comment: Seeing same thing, does anybody found what's the problem?